# Why doesn't Automapper inherit ForPath-ignores?

Tags: c#, automapper

We are mapping domain hierarchy to the Dto hierarchy. Some of the properties of the domain base class get flattened. We are using ReverseMap to simplify the mapping back to domain from dto.

We've mapped Contained.Id do ContainedId of Dto and ignored the path for the reverse map.
What we were expecting, that mapping back to domain object shouldn't create new instances for Contained-property. But that was not the case.
After some investigations we've found out, that it was due to not-inheriting the .ForPath(, opt => opt.Ignore()) for the ReverseMap.

We are using 9.0.0 version of Automapper.

Here is the code:

```
    public class Contained {
        public Guid Id { get; set;  }
    }
    public class Base {
        public Contained Contained { get; set;}
    }
    public class Derived: Base { }

    public abstract class BaseDto {
        public Guid? ContainedId { get; set; }
    }
    public class DerivedDto: BaseDto { }

    [Test]
    public void ForPathInheritanceWorks()
    {
        var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<Base, BaseDto>()
                .IncludeAllDerived()
                .ReverseMap()
                .ForPath(d => d.Contained.Id, opt => opt.Ignore());
            cfg.CreateMap<Derived, DerivedDto>()
                .ReverseMap();
        });

        var mapper = configuration.CreateMapper();

        var derived = mapper.Map<Derived>(new DerivedDto());

        Assert.That(derived.Contained, Is.Null); // fails, because derived.Contained is not null.
    }
```

To workaround an issue we had to add

```
.ForPath(d => d.Contained.Id, opt => opt.Ignore())
```

after ReverseMap of the derived class.

For me it looks like a bug in Automapper.

Comment: A bug is a strong word, as both `ForPath` and inheriting `Ignore` are relatively new features, but yes, it makes sense and we can try to fix it.

Comment: Why even use `ReverseMap` and then disable what it does? You can simply not use it and create the map yourself, or write your own version of `ReverseMap` without the undesired behaviour.

Comment: You are right. If I simply map Dto to Domain, than everything works as expected for the simple case above.
I'll try to check in the production case whether it is a better way to work with mappings. We've used ReverseMaps, because of other properties / in other cases and made it to the common practice to "reverse maps".

Comment: We've also noticed another strange effect, that is possibly related to that one - that IncludeAllDerived doesn't get reversed: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62085856/13625178